# Let $G$ be a non-abelian group, $|G|=12$. If $G$ has a normal $2$-Sylow, then $G$ is isomorphic to $A_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group, $|G|=12$. If $G$ has a normal $2$-Sylow, then $G$ is isomorphic to $A_4$.

What I've done so far: I know that $A_4$ has $8$ $3$-cycles, $3$ elements of order $2$, and the unit. Thanks to the Sylow's theorems I've also found out that $n_3=4$ (if it was $n_3=1$, then $G\simeq D\times T$, where $D \in {\rm Syl}_2(G)$, $T \in{\rm Syl}_3(G)$, and it'd be abelian), hence $G$ has $8$ elements of order $3$. I'd like to conclude now that $D \in{\rm Syl}_2(G)$ is not cyclic, meaning that $D$ has $3$ elements of order $2$ and $G$ has basically the same structure as $A_4$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to try to determine the structure of the Sylow $2$-subgroup.

You've used the fact that $G$ has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup to conclude that it must have four Sylow $3$-subgroups. Great. Now let $G$ act by conjugation on the set of Sylow $3$-subgroups; this induces a morphism $\varphi\colon G\to S_4$. Because there are four Sylow $3$-subgroups, each of them is equal to its own normalizer (because the index of the normalizer needs to be equal to the size of the orbit). Use that to show the kernel of $\varphi$ is trivial and hence that it is an isomorphism onto $A_4$ (as that is the only subgroup of index $2$ in $S_4$).

Comment: Is it $A_4$ and not $S_4$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: oops; yes, thank you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok, so the normalizers have order $3$, hence their intersection must be trivial for them to be distincts subgroups; but the kernel of that morphism is the intersection of all the normalizers, so the kernel is trivial too, is that right?

Comment: @Wallace: Yes. That is correct.